# How to force a commit as the new head of a protected branch after a reset?

Tags: git

So I had made some changes to some code that was running just fine so I pushed it to origin master. I come to it the next day and by some mystery (I know what happened now but it doesn't matter), things stop working. I say fine I'll just go back to the previous version by 'git reset --hard foo. I redo what I had done the correct way so the problem doesn't happen again but git wants me to pull before I can push these changes saying:

```
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind 
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
```

Is there a way to essentially disregard the current head of the branch and replace it with what I have now?

I should have noted this is a protected branch.

Comment: You need to force-push: `git push -f`

Comment: it won't let me since its a protected branch

Answer (score 1):

after you locally reverted the head use `git push -f` to force the server to update it and override its history.

#### EDIT: seeing this is about a protected branch this wont work of course.

you may want to locally revert the commit with `git revert` and add the resevert commit to tip of branch. it will be in history though...

(if you can git push to it normally: cool)
(else you make another Pull Request of it)
(github also a GUI option for this IIRC though I never tried it)

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change config to allow force push (even temporarily) for whatever reason, then your best way forward would be to reset:

```
git checkout the-revision-with-the-content-the-way-i-want-it-to-be-like
git reset --soft origin/master # or whatever branch you are talking about
git commit -m "Taking back history"
git push origin HEAD:master (or whatever branch you are working on)
```

That should hold